# How to copy directory structure of a certain directory

Tags: terminal, directory, copy

Is there a 1 line cmd command to copy the directory structure of a certain directory and not the files?

Something like:

```
Source:
rootDir
    -filename1
    -filename2
    -justName
    -otherName
    -dirA
        -dirAFile_ver01
        -dirAFile_ver02
    -dirB
        -dirBFile_01
        -dirBFile_02
        -dirBFile1
        -dirBFile2
    -dirC
        -dirCFile01
        -dirCFile02
        -dirD
            -dirDFile-01
            -dirDFile-02
            -dirDFile.0.1
            -dirDFile.0.2
            -dirDFile.1
    -dirE
        -file1.jpg
        -file2.jpg
        -file1.txt
        -file2.txt

Copied into:
rootDir
    -dirA
    -dirB
    -dirC
        -dirD
    -dirE
```

Comment: sorry just noticing typo, rephrasing:

Comment: Is there a 1 line cmd command to copy the directory structure but not the files ? tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simple solution would be using `rsync`:

```sh
rsync -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" "$source/" "$destination/"
```

The first `-f` is to copy all directories and second `-f` is not copy anything else.

Another way with `rsync` is to include directories in the first place and then exclude all the files:

```sh
rsync -av --include='*/' --exclude='*' "$source/" "$destination/"
```

You can do something like this with `find`:

```sh
cd "$source" && find . -type d -exec mkdir -p -- "$destination/{}" \;
```